# string to time from user input

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a register page that has 3 drop down boxes for day month and year
these are set up for day in number format - (1-31) month (01-12) and year (1993)ect.

Now I'm having issues putting it to timestamp.

Tried:

```
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$Dob = strtotime($month . " " . $day . " " . $year);
```

But its not giving me any output :(. do I need to have the day month year organised in a special way?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't give you any output? It will always return at least `false` (or -1 on older versions of PHP) if it fails to parse the date.

Comment: Can you try `strtotime($month . "-" . $day . "-" . $year);`

Comment: im putting info to a db, and its not inserting it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['day']) || empty($_POST['year'])) {
  // handle invalid input, at least one of month, day, year wasn't given
} else if (!checkdate($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'])) {
  // handle invalid date, such as February 30th
} else {
  // convert to epoch (unix timestamp)
  $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year']);
}
```

Aside from that, three `<select>`s for date-input are very 1998ish. Why not use `<input type="date">` instead? This allows browsers to pop up a date-picker (which can be polyfilled).

Comment: Thanks mate! that helped :), was trying to use the date input but couldnt seem to get the layout right :).]

Answer (score 1):

```
$Dob = strtotime($day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year);
```

**Note:**

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
1) Never assume the data is safe from user input, even it is from a drop-down.  The (int) forces each item to be a integer.  While not significant in this case, it becomes VERY important for database storage to always sanitize the data input.

2) You just need slashes between.  `strtotime` recognizes [These Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

```
$Dob = strtotime((int)$month . "/" . (int)$day . "/" . (int)$year);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to follow one of the predefined date format type, as cited on the manual page.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php